# File compression and codes

Tags: c, lzw

I'm implementing a version of lzw. Let's say I start off with 10 bit codes and increase whenever I max out on codes. For example after 1024 codes, I'll need 11 bits to represent 1025. Issue is in expressing the shift.

How do I tell decode that I've changed the code size? I thought about using 00, but the program can't distinguish between 00 as an increment and 00 as just two instances of code zero.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which language are you using to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. You shift to a new size when the dictionary is full. The decoder's dictionary is built synchronized with the encoder's dictionary, so they'll both be full at the same time, and the decoder will shift to the new size exactly when the encoder does.

The time you have to send a code to signal a change is when you've filled the dictionary completely -- you've used all of the largest codes available. In this case, you *generally* want to continue using the dictionary until/unless the compression rate starts to drop, then clear the dictionary and start over. You do need to put some marker in to tell when that happens. Typically, you reserve the single largest code for this purpose, but any code you don't use for any other purpose will work.

Edit: as an aside, note that you normally want to start with codes exactly one bit larger than the codes for the input, so if you're compressing 8-bit bytes, you want to start with 9 bit codes.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the LZW algorithm.

When decompressing you automatically build up the code dictionary again. When a new code exactly fills the current number of bits, the code size has to be increased.

For the details see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch#Variable-width_codes).

Answer (score 1):

You increase the number of bits when you create the code for 2<sup>n</sup>-1. So when you create the code 1023, increase the bit size immediately. You can get a better description from the [GIF compression scheme](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~amer/CISC651/lzw.and.gif.explained.html). Note that this was a patented scheme (which partly caused the creation of PNG). The patent has probably expired by now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the decoder builds the same table as the compressor, its table is full on reaching the last element (so 1023 in your example), and as a consequence, the decoder knows that the next element will be 11 bits.